# Show the results of jobs scheduled with cron in the terminal

Tags: linux, cron

I've sucessfully configured a script that scans my system using cron in a scheduled hour of a day. However, I would like to see the results that it might have generated with its execution. Ex: rkhunter -c leaves logs in /var/log/rkhunter.log that I manually would have to check after it performed the task.

How can I configure cron to show a terminal with its results for example?
I've seen a similar case to mine, but it didn't work:

```
minute hour * * *  DISPLAY=:0 xterm -e /dir_to_my_script/script.sh
```

But it gave the following error that I've not been able to solve so far:

*Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s*

Is there a way to accomplish it using cron as root? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you put the output in a file, and then just look at the file in the terminal.

Comment: If the cron job is running as root, it won't be able to open X windows on a different user's display.

Comment: I wanted this, but wanted the file to be displayed to me right after the job was done. Because you see, every time I have the task completed it does save everything in the log file that I said earlier. But I need to go after the file in order to see it...If I could just see have the file displayed. It would be much more practical. Since the log file at some point may become to large. Understand?